# '\begin{document}' giving 'Overfull' warning

Tags: formatting, overleaf, resume

I am new to Latex. In the code below I am getting a warning at 'begin{document}' line saying:

> 'Overfull \hbox (30.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 28 - 28'

I am inheriting a custom style called 'resume.cls' and I tried erasing everything below line 28 and recompiling, but the warning doesn't go away.

Please help.
Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{resume} 
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{setspace} \usepackage[left=0.4in,top=0.3in,right=0.4in,bottom=0.2in]{geometry} 
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2667\textwidth}\rlap{#1}} \newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}} 
\name{John Doe} 
\address{ Stockholm, Sweden \\  www.linkedin.com/in/johnd/ } 
\address{ +46760011224 \\ johndoe3110@gmail.com } 
    \begin{document} 
    \singlespacing
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which class `resume` do you use? Do you have a link to it?

Comment: https://github.com/treyhunner/resume/blob/master/resume.cls

Comment: the class redefines \document and so breaks with recent releases that use a slightly different defition of \document. That could be fixed but why that class?  There are several maintained classes for CV/resume available

Answer (score 1):

Class `resume.cls` you are using is outdated and should not be used any longer.

For example you can use class `moderncv` with style `banking` with an resulting layout similar to the layout of class `resume`.

Please see the following two PDFs (results of class `resume` and `moderncv`):

[image: Result of class resume]

[image: Result of class moderncv]

This is the MWE for class `moderncv`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-golden-upright}%
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description 
  no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description 
  line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{\textbf{Language} 2}{\textbf{Skill} level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3. This item is particularly long and therefore 
  normally spans over several lines. Did you notice the indentation 
  when the line wraps?}

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{Item 6. Like item 3 in the single column list before, this item is particularly long to wrap over several lines.}

\section{References}
\begin{cvcolumns}
  \cvcolumn{Category 1}{\begin{itemize}\item Person 1\item Person 2\item Person 3\end{itemize}}
  \cvcolumn{Category 2}{Amongst others:\begin{itemize}\item Person 1, and\item Person 2\end{itemize}(more upon request)}
  \cvcolumn[0.5]{All the rest \& some more}{\textit{That} person, and \textbf{those} also (all available upon request).}
\end{cvcolumns}


\clearpage
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper 
neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque 
arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi 
volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis 
tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat 
vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis 
ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque 
orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut 
odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. 
Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per 
inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec 
tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt 
odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing 
sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla 
consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec 
velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus 
et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna 
libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, 
tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci 
lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam 
venenatis.

Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]

\makeletterclosing

\end{document}
```